# How to export report from Devexpress End user designer?

Tags: devexpress, vb.net-2010

I have used standard report designer in winform and added a button "Export to PDf" in designer bar.

I want that when i click on this button , opened report or edited report in designer should be exported in pdf.

Please give solution to do this.

Comment: what problem are you facing during export.. If you enable export feature in  designer then it will also allow you to filter the export file types also.. what have you implemented in code??

Comment: Thanks Niranjan!  How can I enable export feature in designer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a button in the ribbon and enable the export command with that button. See the below code snippet from the DevExpress sample project for reports in version 14.2.5.

Create a button item in PrintPreview tab and specify it's properties as below:

```
private DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Preview.PrintPreviewBarItem printPreviewBarItem23;

this.ribbonControl1.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem[] {
.....
this.printPreviewBarItem23
.....
};

// 
// printPreviewBarItem23
// 
this.printPreviewBarItem23.ButtonStyle = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonStyle.DropDown;
this.printPreviewBarItem23.Caption = "Export To";
this.printPreviewBarItem23.Command = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemCommand.ExportFile;
this.printPreviewBarItem23.ContextSpecifier = this.xrDesignRibbonController1;
this.printPreviewBarItem23.Enabled = false;
this.printPreviewBarItem23.Glyph = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("printPreviewBarItem23.Glyph")));
this.printPreviewBarItem23.Id = 91;
this.printPreviewBarItem23.LargeGlyph = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("printPreviewBarItem23.LargeGlyph")));
this.printPreviewBarItem23.Name = "printPreviewBarItem23";
```

-GUI view
[image]

You can add a single command button to just export it to pdf, but you need to check for that specific properties you need to set on the control. You can do above programmatic work in Report designer.

Hope this help.